# How can I filter a part of my char

Tags: c++, char, arduino

I have a `char buffer[200];` Its content is (`Serial.println(buffer)`'s output):

```
AT+CGPSINF=2

2,195941,4613.161699,N,608.476854,E,1,9,1.398636,435.450073,M,48.200287,M,,0000
OK
```

I would like to have in `char fix[]` only this

```
2,195941,4613.161699,N,608.476854,E,1,9,1.398636,435.450073,M,48.200287,M,,0000
```

I spent a lot of time working around this code but without success

```
static int gps_read () {

  read_AT_string("AT+CGPSINF=2",3000);
  Serial.println(F("------- Show buffer------"));
  Serial.println(buffer);
  Serial.println(F("-------------------------\n"));

  char fix[BUFFERSIZE];

  int z = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int w = 0;

  for(y=0; y < BUFFERSIZE; y++)
  {
    if(buffer[y]==',') z++;

    if(z > 0){
      if(buffer[y] == '\n') break;

      fix[w] = buffer[y];
      w++;
    }

    //if(y==num)//if the command is right, run return
    //  y=strlen(buffer)+1;
  }
  Serial.println(F("------- Show Fix------"));
  Serial.println(fix);
  Serial.println(F("----------------------"));
```

How can I fill and resize the `char fix[]` with the line which look like:

> 2,195941,4613.161699,N,608.476854,E,1,9,1.398636,435.450073,M,48.200287,M,,0000

In my above code, it prints me that:

```
------- Show Fix------
,202653,4613.164908,N,608.479232,E,1,9,1.183249,427.253052,M,48.200226,M,,0000
b

----------------------
```

I lost first '2'.
The newline and the 'b' and space should be removed.

Comment: You can't resize an automatic native array.

Comment: Have you considered not reading *into* `fix` until you get where you want to start, and stopping putting characters in once you get to the end?

Comment: I found a solution but I am not satisfied about, what do you recommand me? Tks

Comment: This don't look as C++ code but as nearly C code.

Comment: Please tell **what** you want to skip - first two lines? First 14 characters? At the moemnt, the question is IMO unclear.

Comment: Dear Sir, I would like to skip all line excepted line containing : 2,195941,4613.161699,N,608.476854,E,1,9,1.398636,435.450073,M,48.200287,M,,0000. At the end, I would like to have just 1 line with the 15 parameters, between the ','. Did I answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I solve like this, but I am not satisfied.

```
char* gps_read (void) {

  if(strstr(read_AT_string("AT+CGPSINF=2",3000),"OK") != NULL)
  {
    Serial.println(F("------- Show buffer------"));
    Serial.println(buffer);
    Serial.println(F("-------------------------\n"));

    char fix[BUFFERSIZE];

    int z = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w = 0;

    for(y=0; y < BUFFERSIZE; y++)
    {
      if(buffer[y]==',') z++;

      if(z > 0){
        if(buffer[y] == '\n'){
          fix[w-1]='\0';
          break;
        }

        fix[w] = buffer[y+1];
        w++;
      }

    }
    Serial.println(F("------- Show Fix------"));
    Serial.println(fix);
    Serial.println(F("----------------------"));

    return fix;
  }
  else
  {
    return "Error : no fix";
  }
}
```

It's not important of '2,' is not display. 
How would you do better?